# How do I speed up egg hatching?

Tags: pokemon-series

Some Pokemon eggs take many thousands of in-game steps to hatch. I'm only interested in breeding in late parts of the game, mostly after I have beaten the League. Since I've already done virtually all the things I wanted to do, I only generate a minimum of steps.

**Is there some way of speeding up the hatching?** I don't want to press D-pad arrows all day just so I can get an egg to hatch.

**Edit:** I'm playing Heart Gold, in case it's relevant.

Comment: @Michel: Could you please explain the Rollback? I think that OP was clear that the question is for Heart Gold, hence the tag [tag:pokemon-hgss]...

Comment: Take a look at the debate [on the bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13757580#13757580)

Comment: @Michel My take then: the general solution to the question starts at gen III, where abilities were introduced. This question thus is not looking for solutions from Gen II. Second, the Bike Road itself is only in games where the Kanto region is. In other games, it's easier to 'bike' in front of the daycare, or somewhere else (Lumiose city for Gen VI). Third, who knows what mechanics will be introduced later on? [snip]

Comment: ... Case in point, O-Power hatching was just introduced and wouldn't help the OP at all in this case, nor other players playing Pokemon HeartGold. In the worst cases, other mechanics get into scope and the question gets too broad.

Comment: What would happen if another question were asked about how to speed up egg hatching in general?

Comment: @SaintWacko The answer, I believe will be longer than the combined answers up to now, for sure. And for potential future generations, will likely have to be updated.

Comment: Bike Road is specific to one game, correct?  So the accepted answer doesn't even apply to other games.  Our general guideline is to allow questions to be reasked for separate games, even if the answer *hasn't* changed, since it very well *could* have changed *(or could still change in a future patch)*, so I don't see why we're changing that rule for pokemon.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Bike Road is specific to the Kanto Region, so it occurs in Gold/Silver/Crystal, FireRed/LeafGreen and HeartGold/SoulSilver only for games having eggs (and the Bike Roads of Gen VI and Gen III games are nothing similar to it in terms of having a long straight line devoid of obstacles). There are thus 3 sets of games where it applies (GSC, FRLG, HGSS), and 5 sets of games (RSE, DPPt, BW, BW2, XY) it doesn't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [Toomai states](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42573/12936), having a Pokémon with [Flame Body](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Flame_Body) or [Magma Armor](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Magma_Armor) helps tremendously.

While the effect of having two Pokémon with the same ability doesn't stack, the efficiency of the ability can be multiplied by up to five by carrying more than one egg at a time.

Finally, there is a bit of a trick that'll significantly simplify the issue: When on the [Bike Road](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kanto_Route_17), half of your movement is handled for you, and an unblocked avenue that runs from top to bottom can be found on the far left side of the bridge.

This means that you only have to press and hold the up button on the D-pad; and this can be done with a rhythm that is very easy to do with complete absence of mind, often allowing you to at the very least read or watch something else as you slog along.

Comment: I so hoped this wouldn't be the best solution available. :( Oh, well.

Comment: @ver: If you are working towards shinies, don't forget [Masuda](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Masuda_method)!

Comment: If I have one with **Flame body** and another with **magma armor** it'll make it faster to hatch the eggs in my other slots?

Comment: @Michel: As far as I know, *Flame Body* and *Magma Armor* stack neither with their selves, or one another.

Answer (score 13):

If you have a Pokémon with **Flame Body** or **Magma Armor** in your party, then each step towards hatching eggs will count as 2 steps (halving the number of steps needed). The effect doesn't stack if you have multiple Pokémon with the ability at once.

Comment: What about one pokemon with each ability?

Comment: "However, this effect will not stack up if multiple Pokémon with Flame Body and Magma Armor are in the party. " From the link in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

For future reference and people who find this through the search dialog, I'll add some sneaky tricks for other games:

**Diamond / Pearl**

These 2 games contain the Tweaking glitch, which lets you enter the "Void", which is the black area outside of the visible map (parts of that area can be seen when you're standing close to a wall in a building). In this area, since there are few colliders, you can walk/run/bike indefinitely (actually, around 65000 steps before you run into something, but yeah...) as long as you find a clear path (which exist in great numbers). Numerous resources on the Internet explain how Tweaking works and what paths exist (although most are related to reaching Darkrai or Shaymin).
Note that this bears the risk of your game freezing when you Egg hatches in an area that would make it freeze if you saved, so it might not always work and you might need to find different paths for each number of steps.

To run indefinitely without actually pressing the D-Pad all the time, just put something heavy (like a can or some heavy tool) on it that locks it in position. Some sort of clip or tape might also work.

If you're using a 3DS, you can use a small coin to **lock the joystick in any direction**. This also applies to the Gen 6 trick.

---

**X / Y**

In Lumiose City, the Plaza outside the Prism Tower is round and contains a clear path all around. Just go there and lock the joystick as described above. **Talonflame** is a great Pokemon for hatching as it has Flame Body and can learn Fly (to get to the Central Plaza faster).
Also, don't forget to use the Hatching O-Power to speed the process up even more.

---

**General**

This is just pointing out the obvious (and is implicit to Willihams answer), but you should always **ride your bike** while hatching. This increases the rate of steps vs. actual time spent.